# Invalid Scope:basic_info. Use public_profile,user_friends instead

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I am using "Sign in with facebook" functionality in my iOS application.
When i do select "Sign in with facebook" option application is redirected to safari and shows facebook login form. When i complete with email and password and press login,i am getting error like "Invalid Scope:basic_info. Use public_profile,user_friends instead." from my iOS application. I am using Facebook SDK.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You are using basic_info in scope parameter.To get public informations use public_profile permission instead.

Comment: When was this changed? Can you link to any docs from Facebook on this?

Comment: Found it -> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1#reference-public-profile